# i have changed the DB of my application and if i ll upload to apple store then what will happen ?

Tags: ios, database

I have an application on apple store , due to some issue i have added one field in the DB of my Application .

My Query is: When i change application's DB i have to delete the existing application from simulator and then re install the application on Simulator , but when some one install it from app store then Do my customer also have to delete the existing application and then install the new one or what will happen in this DB change case ??
Or do i have to try something in code ??
Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to do database migration. Database migration enabled existing users of your application to install updates without having to delete old version. Also there old datas will migrate to the new version.

Are you using core data?  If you are using core data then you should read [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004399-CH1-SW1) on core data migration.

Comment: well i didn't use core data , i have used SQLite for my application it will be great if i can have some code or and reference regarding SQLite also .

Answer (score 0):

If your application is storing any user specific data, you should not force the user to delete the application.

When you upload the new version, it should have provision to upgrade the DB. You can do it programmatically. To identify if user has upgraded or  not, you can add some custom key into your .plist file or by any other mean. Once identify either you can migrate your core data or you can migrate your existing sqlite3 db by update table query.

Comment: in my application i am copying the DB from code so i dnt know to update the existing installed DB , well if some one installs a new version then no issues but how to delete the Old one replace with new DB , please give a snippet